# Drop down not loading value in a dialog box opened with values from Data table in primefaces and JSF project

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am working on a JSF, primefaces based project. I have a tab where I load the database records in a data table. With every record in the data table, I have a button to edit the details. On click of this button I open a dialog box for updating the details.
The fields on this dialog box load the value perfectly except a drop down. I have commented that from the code below, because If I uncomment this drop down code, it stops the dialog box to load values and the error thrown is "Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, [selectedRole] returned null". If I do not display this drop down on dialog box, the dialog box works perfectly.  Please help me to fix this drop down values and display the saved value in the drop down in the dialog box.

The field is available in the Dialog box: roleDialog with value as #{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole.roleStatus}.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body onload="clearAllPrimeFaceFilters()">
    <style>
        .messagePanel{
        padding: 0px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .label{
        width: 80px;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        .value {
        width: 150px;
        color: #3971ae;
        }
    </style> 
 
 <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <p:dataTable id="basicDT" var="role" value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.roleList}"  selection="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole}"  >
        <f:facet name="header" >Existing Roles</f:facet>
        
            <p:column headerText="Role ID" styleClass="label" filterBy="#{role.roleID}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{role.roleID}" styleClass="value"/>
            </p:column>
        
            <p:column headerText="Role Title" styleClass="label" filterBy="#{role.roleTitle}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{role.roleTitle}"  styleClass="value" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Date Last Reviewed" styleClass="label" filterBy="#{role.dateLastReviewed}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{role.dateLastReviewed}"  styleClass="value"/>
            </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Role Original Document" style="width:120px;text-align:center">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Download Role Original Document" styleClass="label"/>
          </f:facet>
          <p:commandButton  value="Download" ajax="false" actionListener="#{roleMaintenanceBean.downloadRoleOriginalDocument(role)}">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.originalRoleDocumentToDownload}"/>
          </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
                    
                    
            <p:column  headerText="Edit" style="width:3rem;text-align: center">
                <p:commandButton title="Update" icon="ui-icon-pencil" update="@form:roleDetail" 
                actionListener="#{roleMaintenanceBean.setSelectedRole(role)}" oncomplete="PF('roleDialog').show()">
                   <!--  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{role}" target="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole}"/> -->
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </div>
     <p:dialog header="Role Details" widgetVar="roleDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
               dynamic="true" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                
        <h:panelGrid title="Role Details" id="roleDetail" columns="4" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
            
            
            <h:outputLabel value="Role ID" styleClass="label" />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole.roleID}" styleClass="value"></h:outputLabel>
                    
            <h:outputLabel value="Role Title" styleClass="label"/>              
                <h:inputText value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole.roleTitle}" styleClass="value"></h:inputText>
            
                <h:outputLabel value="Division" styleClass="label"/>              
                <h:inputText value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole.division}" styleClass="value"></h:inputText>
            
            <h:outputText value="Date Last Reviewed" styleClass="label"/>
               <p:calendar value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole.dateLastReviewed}"
              pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" styleClass="value">
               </p:calendar>


            <h:outputText value="Role Status" styleClass="label"/>
            <!-- <p:selectOneMenu value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole.roleStatus}">
               <f:selectItems value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.roleStatusList}"></f:selectItems>
             </p:selectOneMenu> -->
                     
                        
            <h:outputText value="Role Description Original Document" styleClass="label"/>           
            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{roleMaintenanceBean.roleDescFileUpdateListener}"
                update="orgFileName"
            immediate="true" auto="true"/>                                      
                   
                   <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{roleMaintenanceBean.updateRoleDetails}"
                    process="@form,@widgetVar(confirmationVar)" update="@form:basicDT @form:confirmationID">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole}"
                        target="#{roleMaintenanceBean.selectedRole}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="PF('roleDialog').hide()"></p:commandButton>
             </f:facet>   
             
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
    
     <p:confirmDialog id="confirmationID" widgetVar="confirmationVar" header="Confirmation" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode"
                    message="Role updated successfully" closable="true">
    <p:commandButton value="OK" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-ok" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('confirmationVar').hide(); PF('roleDialog').hide()"/>
    </p:confirmDialog>  
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The list roleStatusList is populated in the bean RoleMaintenanceBean with enumeration values.  The field roleStatus is defined with annotation Enumerated. The bean is in View Scope.

```
@Column(name = "Role_Status", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleStatusEnum roleStatus;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `selectedRole` to a new item, on page load? Else, can you post the significant code of bean classes, involved in this problem?

Comment: Its a dialog box. If i keep the role status as a text box, it loads fine with value. The problem is when I make it a selectOneMenu (drop down), then selectedRole is null is thrown. I think I won't need to set the selectedRole on Dialog box on load. It is already getting the values and loading fine. The problem is only when it is dropdown, I see this error.